# [NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

I'm programming a app on Swift 2, and i receive this error when launch the app:

```
2015-12-21 11:13:43.706 MyApp[8454:3313990] -[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0000726f7272655
2015-12-21 11:13:43.713 MyApp[8454:3313990] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0000726f7272655'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183a65900 0x1830d3f80 0x183a6c61c 0x183a695b8 0x18396d68c 0x1000bee2c 0x1000bf49c 0x1000bf5c8 0x1000c7418 0x1000c7514 0x1887580c0 0x188757cc4 0x18875eab4 0x18875bfa0 0x1887d1cd0 0x1889fc358 0x188a004b8 0x1889fd5c0 0x18501b790 0x18501bb10 0x183a1cefc 0x183a1c990 0x183a1a690 0x183949680 0x1887c6580 0x1887c0d90 0x10016da94 0x1834ea8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

[Thread 1: signal SIGABRT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDws9.png)

On Story boards i don't have any yellow flag on my screenControllers.

EDIT:

The two last methods launched before the exception are:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
        var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Favs.sqlite")
        var error: NSError? = nil
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        let mOptions = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
        do{
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)

        }catch{
            coordinator = nil
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            print("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()        }

        return coordinator
    }()
```

and

```
  lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator == nil {
            return nil
        }
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()
```

---

Solved.
--The problem is related with deprecrated import.io library--

Comment: Add `Exception Breakpoint` to get the line where the crash occurs. The error message says that you're calling `objectForKey` on a string rather than on the expected dictionary.

Comment: @vadian the two last methods are:persistentStoreCoordinator and managedObjectContext

Comment: The code looks outdated, for example in Swift 2 `persistentStoreCoordinator` and `managedObjectContext` are non optional. Create a new project with Core Data enabled and copy and paste the code related to the Core Data stack into your project.

Comment: Ok, I'm update the code, also clean the project and restart Xcode, but the exception is the same @vadian

Comment: Look at the backtrace. There must be a place where `objectForKey` (or key subscription) is called by mistake on a string.

Comment: @vadian the problem is solved, i have the access to a string how u say, its a deprecated library of import.io. I remove this library for the moment and the app is running. Thanks so much